# Orange 3 - Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

Tags: python, orange

I'm working on Orange 3 to compare regression models, the objective is to give a workflow ready to use for my co-worker. But this error appears when I try to predict the target variable:

*One or more scorers failed (see more...)
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets*

I tried to keep the target column on my test dataset (without any value), I tried to remove it.. The only solution that worked was to save the train and test dataset before and to put them back without the preprocess and select row/columns steps. So I want to find a more simple solution. Anyone got an idea?

(I'm sorry for my approximative english)

[Workflow I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bn18.png)

[Data info of the train dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvH7j.png)

[Data info of the test dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9woaf.png)